# C++ gRPC TCP error Protocol not available

Tags: c++, tcp, grpc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I successfully compiled the grpc [example helloworld](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld), but when I run the following error appears(then the server starts anyway):

```
E0625 21080 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:223] check for SO_REUSEPORT: 
{
  "created":"@1593068359.950045200",
  "description":"Protocol not available",
  "errno":92,
  "file":"/mnt/.../grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc",
  "file_line":201,"os_error":"Protocol not available",
  "syscall":"getsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT)"
}
E0625 21080 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:327] setsockopt(TCP_USER_TIMEOUT) Protocol not available
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051
```

So the server does compile and run, but unfortunately it does not communicate with the client.

It's worth to mention that I am using WSL for windows:

```
me@com: $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I have not found anything related to this in google. What might be the problem and how can I move towards a solution?

Comment: Appearently this Pr would solve the problem: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/13517

Comment: Is the complaint that the log message is marked as an error and whether it is unclear whether the gRPC server is working properly? With the two protocols, SO_REUSEPORT and TCP_USER_TIMEOUT not available, you would not get the benefits from the two socket options but otherwise the server would "work". I say "work" because there are known issues for cases where TCP_USER_TIMEOUT is not supported - https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A18-tcp-user-timeout.md

Comment: The complaint is, that the grpc implementation does not work, I was unable to initiate communication. I did manage to do that however on a Linux virtual machine. I'm updating the question with the missing info! Thanks!

Comment: According to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16998, the issue is not present since https://github.com/grpc/grpc/commit/e0d9692fa30cf3a7a8410a722693d5d3d68fb0fd